# Integration by parts with cdf

Tags: probability, integration

Is there are any simplification available to 
$$\int_{-\infty}^t(t-x)dF(x)$$ where, $F(x)$ is a cdf.

I tried with integration by parts
$$\left[(t-x)F(x)+\int F(x)dx\right]_{-\infty}^t$$

not sure how to progress beyond this, will the first part at $x=-\infty$ be zero? as $F(-\infty)=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term $(t-x)F(x)$ is zero also at $x=t$. Therefore, the integral simplifies to
$$\int_{-\infty}^t(t-x)\,dF(x) = \int_{-\infty}^t F(x)\,dx $$
More generally, the integral 
$$
\Phi(t)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_a^t (t-x)^{n-1} f(x)\,dx 
$$
performs $n$  integrations of the function $f$: it produces $\Phi$ such that $\Phi^{(n)}=f$ and $\Phi(a)=\dots=\Phi^{(n-1)}(a)=0$.